# Json string replace

Tags: php, javascript, json, str-replace

I am learning json now and have run into an issue:

**I am using  code like this to spit about and array of data:**

```
<?php
 $requiredFieldsArray = array();
    $results = mysql_query("select account_id, display_name, id from field 
where account_id = $holdAcctID and required_flag = 1");
    while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) 
        {
        $requiredFieldsArray[] = $result;
    }
?>
<script language="javascript">
    var requiredFieldsPRS = <?php echo "new Array(". json_encode($requiredFieldsArray).")"; ?>;
</script>
}
```

**It outputs this:**

```
 var requiedFieldsPRS = new Array([{"account_id":"3","display_name":"Project Requested By","id":"15"},{"account_id":"3","display_name":"Project Title","id":"18"},{"account_id":"3","display_name":"Project Type","id":"19"},{"account_id":"3","display_name":"Banner Details","id":"20"},{"account_id":"3","display_name":"Email to Me","id":"2910"}]);;
```

In my code how can I remove the "**[**" and "**]**" from the beginning and end of the array, so it will appear like this?

```
var requiedFieldsPRS = new Array({"account_id":"3","display_name":"Project Requested By","id":"15"},{"account_id":"3","display_name":"Project Title","id":"18"},{"account_id":"3","display_name":"Project Type","id":"19"},{"account_id":"3","display_name":"Banner Details","id":"20"},{"account_id":"3","display_name":"Email to Me","id":"2910"});
```

**Note: The opening and closing brackets are gone in the above output.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trim off leading and ending `[]`s easily enough for this particular example:

```
var requiredFieldsPRS = <?php echo "new Array(". trim(json_encode($requiredFieldsArray), '[]').")"; ?>;
```

However if your Array constructor is not necessary you could just use:

```
var requiredFieldsPRS = <?php echo json_encode($requiredFieldsArray); ?>;
```

Comment: This is probably impossible, but I'll ask, is there, in addition the the method above to remove the '[]', to remove the quotes that surround the keys, but leave them around the values? For example: {"account_id":"3","display_name":"Project Requested By","id":"15"} would output as {account_id:"3",display_name:"Project Requested By",id:"15"}

Comment: @user1176783 You can do that fairly easily with a regex. Try something like `preg_replace('/"([^"]+)":/', '$1:', trim(json_encode($requiredFieldsArray), '[]'))`

Answer (score 0):

try using JSON_FORCE_OBJECT key

```
    json_encode($requiredFieldsArray,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: is this what you meant: var requiredFieldsPRS3 = <?php echo json_encode($requiredFieldsArray,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);?>;  I am getting and empty variable result.

Comment: What is your php version? If its < 5.3.0, than you cant use this option key :)
Instead, try usings substr like: substr(json_encode($var),1,-1) - this will remove square brackets